# dynamic Backgrounds for django using image upload

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, image-uploading

I've looked around and haven't found a satisfactory solution. I am trying to uploaded an image via the Django admin interface using models and then call that uploaded image to be used as the background for a div .i.e - I create football called Salford City, I upload a picture of the team. I will have several teams. If I choose Salford then the background changes, if I choose Brighton Albion then the background changes. I have it working using javascript and hard coded cities but I would like to be able to do it dynamically without have to change base coding to enable easy scaling. Current code is as follows:

Models.py:

```
class City(models.Model):
index = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250, null=False, blank = False, verbose_name = 'City Inner Search Name(lowercase)')
landing_page_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'City Description')
name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank = False, verbose_name = 'City Common Name')
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, verbose_name= 'City Image')
```

The images are stored in media_files/images

The html:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid citybackground">
<!-- <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ City.image.url }}"> -->
```

AS you can see I tried multiple options. The commented out section was a method I tried.

The css:

```
.citybackground
{
background-image: url( "{% images {{City.image.url}} %}");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
```

The views.py:

```
def SetCitySession(request):
  if request.method == "POST":

    request.session['city-name'] = request.POST['cityName']
    request.session['city-id'] = request.POST['cityId']

    return JsonResponse({})


def GetCitySession(request):
  if request.method == "GET":

    cityName = request.session['city-name']
    cityId = request.session['city-id']

    context = {
        "cityName": cityName,
        "cityId": cityId
    }

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

This is currently working hard coded javascript which I want to stop using since it isn't dynamic.

```
function changeBackground(city){
    var urlBackground;

    switch(city){
        case "Manchester":
            urlBackground = "/static/img/fondo_main.jpg";
            break;
        case "Liverpool":
            urlBackground = "/static/img/liverpool_background.jpg";
            break;
        case "London":
            urlBackground = "/static/img/london_background.jpg";
            break;
    }

    $("#main").css("background-image", "url('{% if city.image %}{{ city.image.url }}{% else %}{"+ urlBackground + "}{% endif %}')";
}
```

Thanks ya'll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this question when I was completely new to Django, finishing off an existing project whilst not fully understanding how the system worked. The answer by @yusuf.oguntula is correct in a manner. In the the question I neglected to add the view that actually showed the background image and rather gave the views which where used to retrieve and set session data on the server. Secondly, the actual view did not state which city it was since it had not retrieved the city from django. At the time the city was set by javascript but there was no query set or object retrieval within the view itself so as to allow interaction with python syntax. This meant even though the solution suggested by @yusuf.oguntula was correct it did not work due to the missing query set. I fixed this first by retrieving the appropriate city to the HomepageView in views.py like this:

```
if 'city-name' not in request.session:
    cityName='Madrid'
    request.session['city-name'] = request.POST.get('cityName')

else:
    cityName = request.session['city-name']

city = get_object_or_404(City, name=cityName)
```

and then used @yusuf.oguntula 's solution in my html. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Simply write it as:

```
  background-image: url({{ city.image.url }});
```

Comment: If it does not, check that `city.image.url` actually has a value

Comment: seems  `city.image.url` isn't being given an value. In he console debug section I am getting this: `<div id="main" class="container-fluid citybackground" style="background-image: url()">`  . How do I set the value of city.imgae.url ?

Comment: Oh! I see. Can you show the queryset `city` and you are forming it? Which `Model` class is that referring to?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. As above it is from the `City` class. I wasn't creating a queryset because my understanding is that it is done so as a default. Are you saying I should? What should I make it too for it work in this case?

Comment: There is no city object in the response the template got!

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style for background image

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid citybackground" style="background-image: url({{City.image.url}})">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add inline CSS to the element you want to have a background image. For example,

```
<div style="background: url('{{ home.image.url }}');">
</div>
```

This will work for sure

Comment: It would be good to explain how your answer differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356629/5325862) that was already posted

Comment: style="background-image: url({{City.image.url}})"  this was the code for the css part that was posted earlier. My code is  style="background: url('{{ home.image.url }}');"  You can clearly see the difference that my code do have single quote after url(  and also the style part terminated by a semi-colon